# Multi-part identifier could not be bound -- on an update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, identifier

Below are two examples of what I'm trying to run:

```
UPDATE db1..table1 
    SET tb1.newValue = lt1.udfvalue 
    FROM db2..lookup_table lt1,
        db1..table1 tb1
        WHERE lt1.ID = tb1.ID
        AND lt1.userdefinedfieldtypename = 'Test'


    UPDATE db1..table1 
        SET tb1.NUM=tb2.NUM
        FROM    db1..table1  tb1,
                db1..table1  tb2
        WHERE   tb2.STATUS='Final'
                and tb1.ID=tb2.ID
                and tb1.STATUS='Revised'
                and tb1.NUM is NULL
```

It has something to do with the aliases, but I'm out of ideas right now. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: remove the aliases from the left hand side of the set statements, just use bare columns names.

Comment: You haven't alias `tb1` on your update table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the alias in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tb1 
SET tb1.NUM=tb2.NUM
    FROM    db1..table1  tb1,
        ....
```